Why do these insulated wire ferrules have the same dimensions for different wire gauges?
I've run into this catalog page showing insulated wire ferrules for 26-28, 24-26 and 22-24 AWG having the same dimensions, but different marking colors.

Can someone explain why they don't just make a single part for the whole range 22-28 AWG?

Maybe because they need a different crimping tool size?

@Ale..chenski Why would two ferrules with the same dimensions need a different crimping tools? All three sizes work with SQ28-10 as shown in the table.

One tool model does not mean it does not have different claw sizes for different color codes. The wire diameter is different, so the tool must be different, no?

@Ale..chenski No. I looked up SQ28-10 tool and it doesn't have replaceable dies.

SQ28-10 does not have replaceable dies but does have many different settings.

@Ale..chenski I don't see any settings. It is a simple square crimper: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/american-electrical-inc/SQ28-10/266526

The only difference between the top three sections of the table is the colour, so maybe the colour is a quick indication of the wire gauge.

1: Not all crimping tools out there are SQ28, some have different dies for different gauges. 2: The ferrules are compliant to the standards listed, (DIN, Telemech and Weidmuller) and the standards specify the color difference for the different gauges.


I don't see any settings. It is a simple square crimper.

That is a self adjusting crimper. For some applications they are not allowed. There are limits to how well a simple mechanically self-adjusting crimper can do the crimping job. It is in principle possible to design a linkage that would apply variable crimping force as the dies close up, and release the crimp at the right time. To do it right is tricky and expensive. These cheap crimpers are cheap for a reason. You get what you pay for.
Instead, the ferrule colors match the wire size, and then the color also directs the assembler to use the correct cavity of a multi-cavity crimper. This way, the ferrule selection is made in relation to wire diameter, but when it's time to crimp, a simple color-match is enough to select the right cavity in the crimper.
That's why there are multiple colors for otherwise identical ferrules. The metal tube has the same size, but it needs to be crimped down to a different rectangular area that depends solely on the wire cross-sectional area.

The 3 top ferrules do have the same diameters, but the wire gauge is different, which requires different crimpling tool settings, see "28-10"


Good catch! DigiKey picture was of the other side.
